# How can I monitor the throughput of my Thunderbolt ports in real time?

Tags: thunderbolt

I'd like to see the throughput of my Thunderbolt ports in real time. I'm imagining like the Network packet visualizer in Activity Monitor... but for all the data that's coming in and out of my Thunderbolt port. How can I do this?

[image: network packets]

Use case: I have a M1 MacBook Pro (2020) with two Thunderbolt ports (System Profiler says they're USB4), with a Thunderbolt hub ([Plugable UD-ULTC4K](https://plugable.com/products/ud-ultc4k)) attached. The hub has a ton of stuff attached to it... monitors, ethernet, hard drives... and I'm wondering if I'm creating any kind of bottleneck.

Comment: Thunderbolt is DisplayPort, USB, PCIe, and power.  If this is causing a bottleneck, your PCIe bus and by extension, CPU would be maxed. Your display would lag as would your USB.  What does Activity Monitor say?

Comment: @Allan That's interesting. Right now, the CPU isn't stressed at all. I'll have to do some file transfers and push the network and pay attention to the CPU.

Comment: What model of hub?

Comment: @Gilby It's a [Plugable UD-ULTC4K](https://plugable.com/products/ud-ultc4k).

Comment: My reading of the spec of that hub is that the computer connection is "compatible" with Thunderbolt computer ports, but the connection is USB 3.2 gen2 at 10 Gbs. So the hub will be a bottleneck with many devices connected.